# Geojson data is not properly visible on the archgis map

Tags: reactjs, geojson, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to show Pakistan flood data on the ArcGIS map. the map is loading fine. Geojsos'   point is showing as well but when I click it, it doesn't show any data. Can you please look into this? I feel there is an issue with the layers but unable to troubleshoot. Please look into this?

Here is my map component:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

const loadEsriModules = async () => {
  const [MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate] = await loadModules([
    'esri/views/MapView',
    'esri/WebMap',
    'esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer',
    'esri/PopupTemplate', 
  ]);
  return { MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate }; // Add PopupTemplate to the returned object
};

export default function PakFlood() {
  const mapEI = useRef(null);
  const [mapLoaded, setMapLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initMap = async () => {
      if (mapLoaded) {
        return; // Map has already been loaded, do not load again
      }

      const { MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate } = await loadEsriModules(); // Include PopupTemplate
      let view;

      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const webmap = new WebMap({
          basemap: 'topo-vector',
        });

     //   const centerCoordinates = [69.3451, 30.3753];

        view = new MapView({
          map: webmap,
          center: [69.3451, 30.3753],
          zoom: 5,
          container: mapEI.current,
        });

        try {
          // Simplified Popup Template
          const popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
            title: "Flood Data",
            content: "{Death} deaths, {Injuries} injuries",
          });

          console.log("GeoJSON Layer created");  // Debugging Step 1

          const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
            url: '/GeoJson.json',
            popupTemplate: popupTemplate,
          });

          console.log("Before adding layer:", webmap.layers.length);  // Debugging Step 2

          // Add the GeoJSON layer to the map
          webmap.add(geojsonLayer);

          console.log("After adding layer:", webmap.layers.length);  // Debugging Step 2

          setMapLoaded(true);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("An error occurred:", error);  // Debugging Step 4
        }
      }

      return () => {
        if (view) {
          view.destroy();
        }
      };
    };

    return () => initMap();
  }, []);

  return <div style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }} ref={mapEI}></div>;
}
```

my geojson file is:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Death": 336,
        "Injuries": 106,
        "Home Damaged": "4,26,897"

      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          67.02502796328298,
          30.208618740113437
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Death": 309,
        "Injuries": 348,
        "Home Damaged": "3,26,897"
     
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          71.56406913421023,
          34.166707649222474
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Death": 799,
        "Injuries": 8422,
        "Home Damaged": "57,496"
  
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          66.97593758543181,
          25.004585896445533
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Death": 23,
        "Injuries": 8,
        "Home Damaged": "1,160"

      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          74.31454667531628,
          35.99794367334606
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "Death": 223,
        "Injuries": 3858,
        "Home Damaged": "UNKNOWN"
},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          74.28116274467547,
          31.745012657468934
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having recently finished a map project(only for Nuclear bombs), I feel your pain. To show data when you click a GeoJSON point, you'll need to add a popup template to your GeoJSONLayer. A popup template defines the content displayed in a popup when a user clicks a feature.

Make sure you import the necessary modules from esri-loader.
Create Popup Template to show Death, Injuries, and Home Damaged.
Attach Popup to Layer: Attach the PopupTemplate to your GeoJSONLayer.
Add Layer to Map.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

const loadEsriModules = async () => {
  const [MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate] = await loadModules([
    'esri/views/MapView',
    'esri/WebMap',
    'esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer',
    'esri/PopupTemplate'
  ]);
  return { MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate };
};

export default function PakFlood() {
  const mapEl = useRef(null);
  const [mapLoaded, setMapLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initMap = async () => {
      if (mapLoaded) {
        return; // Map has already been loaded, do not load again
      }

      const { MapView, WebMap, GeoJSONLayer, PopupTemplate } = await loadEsriModules();
      let view;

      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const webmap = new WebMap({
          basemap: 'topo-vector',
        });

        const centerCoordinates = [69.3451, 30.3753];

        view = new MapView({
          map: webmap,
          center: centerCoordinates,
          zoom: 5,
          container: mapEl.current,
        });

        // Create a PopupTemplate
        const popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
          title: "Flood Data",
          content: [
            {
              type: "fields",
              fieldInfos: [
                { fieldName: "Death", label: "Deaths" },
                { fieldName: "Injuries", label: "Injuries" },
                { fieldName: "Home Damaged", label: "Homes Damaged" },
              ],
            },
          ],
        });

        // Create a GeoJSONLayer using your GeoJSON data
        const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
          url: '/GeoJson.json',
          popupTemplate: popupTemplate, // Attach the popup template
        });

        // Add the GeoJSON layer to the map
        webmap.add(geojsonLayer);

        setMapLoaded(true);
      }

      return () => {
        if (view) {
          view.destroy();
        }
      };
    };

    initMap();
  }, [mapLoaded]);

  return <div style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }} ref={mapEl}></div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response I tried earlier with the popup template too but it is not showing the data on the map.  here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/thSWhJb

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like you are missing the [CSS](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/get-started/#1-install-and-set-up) or it is not loading properly in your configuration. Just noticed, you are using esri-loader. It provides a way to [load the css by default](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader#loading-styles).

Comment: @odoenet, Thanks so much!! I have added missing CSS and the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without see the full code, but you can run some logs:

```
const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
            url: '/GeoJson.json',
            popupTemplate: popupTemplate,
          });

console.log("Before adding layer:", webmap.layers.length);  // Debugging Step 2

          // Simplified Popup Template
          const popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
            title: "Flood Data",
            content: "{Death} deaths, {Injuries} injuries"  // Debugging Step 3
          });

          const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
            url: '/GeoJson.json',
            popupTemplate: popupTemplate,
          });

          console.log("GeoJSON Layer created");  // Debugging Step 1

          webmap.add(geojsonLayer);

          console.log("After adding layer:", webmap.layers.length);  // Debugging Step 2

          setMapLoaded(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);  // Debugging Step 4
      }
    };

    initMap();
  }, [mapLoaded]);
```

and tell me what they report, or if you figure it out from the logs, all good!

Comment: thanks for the code. I updated the above code. the issue is still persistent. The code is working fine.